# Hyperref to an equation with aligned jumps to wrong position

Tags: hyperref, labels, aligned

I use the environment `aligned` in the `environment` to obtain only one number. But when I use an `eqref` to jump to the equations, it doesn't located at the top of the first equation.

When I click the hyperref, it will be
[image]
But I hope the first equation can be fully displayed.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    In terms of $H$, the Hamiltonian formulation od the equations of motion for the system is
    \begin{equation}\label{eq}
        \begin{aligned}
            \pdv{H}{p_i}&=\dot{q}_i\\
            -\pdv{H}{q_i}&=\dot{p}_i            
        \end{aligned}
        \qquad i=1,2,\cdots,N
    \end{equation}

Here is a eqref \eqref{eq} point to the equation.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can raise the anchors, either generally or locally for the one equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    In terms of $H$, the Hamiltonian formulation od the equations of motion for the system is
    \AddToHookNext{env/equation/begin}{\renewcommand\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{2cm}}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq}
        \begin{aligned}
            \pdv{H}{p_i}&=\dot{q}_i\\
            -\pdv{H}{q_i}&=\dot{p}_i            
        \end{aligned}
        \qquad i=1,2,\cdots,N
    \end{equation}

Here is a eqref \eqref{eq} point to the equation.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution is effective indeed. But if you need to adjust manually every time, it seems to defeat the purpose of using LaTeX

Comment: well you can define an new environment, which first measures the height of the equation and changes the raise length accordingly. The question is if it worth your time to program that.